# configuring django urls and template

Tags: javascript, python, django

i have a django app where i have to load a same page twice  with slightly different content. I have a login page and i am forcing the user to log out if they login from different machine. They will be logged out and redirected to login page but this time the login page should have extra message like " you have been logged out because ...". On my javascript my authentication function have something like :

```
Window.location = /login/?auth =false
```

for redirection . This will redirect the user back to the login page , but with some extra arguments at the url.

I am using Django.contrib.auth login mechanism. I want to know what changes i have to make in my urls.py and login template to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding a GET parameter you need no changes in the URL config, you only need to take this parameter into account in your view, the following example is assuming you are using function based views:

```
def my_view(request):
  if request.GET.get('auth'):
    alt_login = True
  else:
    alt_login = False
  context = {'alt_login': alt_login}
  return render(request, 'template_path.html', context)
```

In your template you can simply put the following around the optional block:

```
{% if alt_login %}
  you have been logged out because...
{% endif %}
```